# Controlling a button state from the state of an ImageControl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am building a Windows Phone 8 App, and on a particular page I have an image control with an application bar along the bottom, there is an upload button on this bar, this currently displays all the time however it should only be displayed/enabled when there is an image inside the image control (i.e: After a photo has been taken)

How would I go about disabling the button when there is no Image inside the Image Control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged; then have a property that has the enabled type and another property that has the image source. Whenever the image source changes just set the enabled property as well.